# Should an asynchronous swift function retain a strong reference to the object?

Tags: ios, swift, retain-cycle

We implemented and extension to NSData that asynchronously persists the data to a URL.
Here is a short version of the function.

```
extension NSData {

    func writeToURL1(url:NSURL, completion: () -> Void)  {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { [weak self] in

            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            strongSelf.writeToURL(url, atomically: true)

            completion()
            })
    }
}
```

Here is how we use it:

```
var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)
imageData?.writeToURL(someURL) { in ... }
```

The problem of course is if `imageData` gets deallocated before the write operation is completed `strongSelf` will be nil and the completion handler will never be called.

There are two solutions to that problem.

1. remove `[weak self]` (i.e. have a strong reference to `self` in `writeToURL1`.
2. reference `imageData` in the completion block (i.e. `imageData?.writeToURL(someURL) { in imageData = nil ... }`)

What approach is more Swift friendly and what approach should we choose?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You should use a strong reference if you don't want the object to go away from under your feet (and doing so wouldn't create a reference cycle); a weak reference if you don't care if the object goes away from under your feet; an unowned reference if you need the object to be around, and have a strong guarantee that the object won't go away from under your feet, but a strong reference would create a cycle.

In your case, you care that the object might go away, because that means that you won't be able to save it. As you have no guarantee that something else will keep the object alive until that task is completed, you should use a strong reference.

Strong references to `self` in closures are a problem when you carry the closure around because it's easy to end up with a non-obvious reference cycle, but you know for a fact that the reference will be dropped right after the closure is executed, so it's not a problem here.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer makes total sense and we will most likely choose option 1. The reason we were going weak self is we were thinking about using it app wide and wanted the next dev to choose whether to retain it in memory or not rather then just sending it off with no idea. It was about who would have control of the memory, the person calling the function or the process itself.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you just want to strongly capture the reference to the NSData object, so removing the `[weak self]` is the easiest and best approach in my opinion. Usually, weak references are used to avoid retain cycles when capturing in a closure. However, you're not actually creating a retain cycle, simply a one way retain by capturing self in the block. The block is not retained by self, it's simply passed down the call stack into dispatch_async, where it is ultimately invoked and deallocated. So there is no retain cycle to avoid by using `weak self`, you just have a retain occur via the closure which is desirable. That is, you want to keep the data in memory until that closure is invoked.